# Elasticsearch full text search: How to return 0 hits if user query has a word thats missing/unknown in indices

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

How to make elasticsearch return 0 hits if query string from user has a word thats missing/unknown in indices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could change the `default_operator` if your query to `AND`, see the documentation about the [query string query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/query-dsl-query-string-query.html)

Comment: Wouldnt that require every word in the sentence to be in the field? So if the user searches for "quick brown fox", then I will exclude any result that doesnt have all the words "quick", "brown" and "fox" in it.. I dont want that. I Want to return "No results" if the user searches for say "quick brown fox hoolahoop" and the word "hoolahoop" is not in the corpus anywhere.. if that makes sense..

Comment: no it doesnt to me, your example is just another query where every term is combined with an `AND`